# How to use a PHP value in external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a variable in PHP, and I need its value in my JavaScript code. How can I get my variable from PHP to JavaScript?

I have a PHP file with HTML code that looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    //some imports

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a;
        a = <?php echo $row['total']; ?>;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And 'a' should be the axis label in my external .js file:

```
yaxis : {
            axisLabel: alert(a),
            tickColor : '#f5f5f5'
        },
```

Comment: a) `alert` doesn't return anything, so `yaxis.axisLabel` can never have a meaningful value. b) I'm not sure where you include your external file, but I guess it happens before `a` is initialized.

Comment: its not clear what you are willing to achieve though still if you are only looking for using values from PHP to js you can use concatenation..although if you once assign it to some variable all the other scripts will have access to it directly

Comment: @RohitS I wanted to create a chart in javascript but I need some data from my index.php file to create the charts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the PHP value to a HTML element first. Then after the html element has been initialized, access the html value via JavaScript. Either with a script tag at the bottom, with a document ready function, or calling a js function in the body onload=""

```
<body>
<input id="a" value="<? php echo $row['total']; ?>" hidden>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var  a = $('#a').value;
   console.log(a);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: please try to add reference for what you are tying to explain.